# redirecting with php after login within same session

Tags: php, session, redirect, header, location

i am trying to make a site with a backend where some users can edit some content.

I made a folder with an index.php.
I want the users to login on the index.php, and after its valid, they should be redirecting to a site where they can choose what they wanna edit (lets call it the main.php).

So, now i am finished with the login validation. If the Login is valide i am starting a Session

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = 1;
header("location: main.php");
```

and on the main.php i wanted to start like this

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['login']) && ($_SESSION['login'] != 1)){
   header("location: index.php");
}
```

I wanted to redirect back to the index.php if the user is not logged in.
But with that, i will neber be logged in, because main.php dont know the $_SESSION['login']...

The Point where my mistake is and what i somehow didnt get is the Session. How can main.php get the Session from index.php at all? Or what is the best way to solve that?

Comment: You have to start session using `session_start()` every time that you want to access `$_SESSION`. It does not matter you are reading or writing to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the session variable from main.php. In main.php, start the session using

```
session_start();
```

after that you can access  `$_SESSION['login']`

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['login']) && ($_SESSION['login'] != 1)){
header("location: index.php");
}
```

Just remember that the  `session_start();` should be at the top of the page. Like:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['login']) && ($_SESSION['login'] != 1)){
header("location: index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: @hatemjapo accept the answer if it solved your problem.Also, you can check out more on http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 0):

Add `session_start();` before the before accessing the $_SESSION global array. See [`docs`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) it resumes the session

`main.php`:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['login']) && ($_SESSION['login'] != 1)){
   header("location: index.php");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Session is used for passing data across pages. In your case, Yes: Session is necessary. However, to you must make sure that the `$_SESSION`is active on both pages. The Code-Snippets below might illustrate this better:

```
    <?php
        // FILE-NAME: index.php
        //FIRST CHECK IF SESSION EXIST BEFORE STARTING IT:
        if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE  || session_id() == '') {
            session_start();
        }
        // CHECK IF USER HAS CORRECTLY LOGGED IN USING YOUR LOGIC.
        // IF USER IS LOGGED IN, THEN SET THE SESSION TO 1
        // OTHERWISE SET THE SESSION TO NULL...
        $_SESSION['login']      = 0;
        if($userIsLoggedIn){
            $_SESSION['login']  = 1;
            header("location: main.php");
            exit;
        }


    ?>

    <?php
        // FILE-NAME: main.php

        //FIRST CHECK IF SESSION EXIST BEFORE STARTING IT:
        if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE  || session_id() == '') {
            session_start();
        }

        // FILE-NAME: main.php
        if(!isset($_SESSION['login']) && ($_SESSION['login'] != 1)){
            header("location: index.php");
        }
```